# Problems with mktemp

Tags: linux, bash, unix

I'm having problems with mktemp.  I've written a script:

```
tempdir=$(mktemp -t -d mytemp.XXXXXX)

mv ~/Desktop/File_Converted/* "$tempdir"

cd $tempdir

for f in *; do

    Some stuff...

done
```

When I run it I get:

```
$ ~/Desktop/script.sh 
mv: rename /Users/user/Desktop/File_Converted/* to /var/folders/xE/xEV9UA-AFpOdJkN2IrTAArI6Gs/-Tmp-/-d.eiXRhaHY\nmytemp.caNEzp: No such file or directory
/Users/user/Desktop/script.sh: line 21: cd: /var/folders/xE/xEV9UA-AFpOdJkN2IrTAArI6Gs+/-Tmp-/-d.eiXRhaHY: Not a directory
```

I can't seem to find what I've done wrong.  Any help, please?

Thanks!

Dan

Comment: There's not any way that you're getting that error message from the script you posted. Also, you need to quote the variable in the `cd` command.

Comment: What is the output of `ls -l ~/Desktop/File_Converted/*`? (With the asterisk, so we can figure out why the glob doesn't work with `mv`.)

Comment: Two other longshot suggestions: what is the value of `GLOBIGNORE`, and what happens if you run your script after executing `shopt -s failglob`?

Answer (score 3):

You've got your `-t` and your `-d` mixed up.

The `-t` argument to mktemp takes an argument, and in your case it's taking `-d`.  Because of that, you're getting a filename instead of a directory, and the `mv` is failing.

The error is extra confusing because mktemp is taking your intended template (`mytemp.XXXXXX`), and *also* generating a temporary name based on it.  That's why you've got a `\n` in the error message, the output from mktemp was actually two lines long.

The relevant docs:

> mktemp [**-d**] [**-q**] [**-t** *prefix*] [**-u**] template ...
>
> **-d**      Make a directory instead of a file.
>
> **-t** *prefix*
>                Generate a template (using the supplied prefix and TMPDIR if set)
>                to create a filename template.

Per your comment,
For debugging, I recommend printing the value of `$tempdir` and seeing if it's what you expect it to be.  That you still appear to be getting two mv errors suggests to me that something is wrong.

The `set -e` command to bash that causes scripts to stop after encountering an error can also be quite handy in tracking down problems like this.

Comment: Thanks, but I tried with both just -t and with -d -t and came up with no such file or directory.

Comment: Maybe [chepner's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/10956462/85950) is the root of what's really going on?

Comment: Weird.  I checked and the temp directory is there and is a directory but I still get Dan-Dows-MacBook-Pro:-Tmp- ddow$ ~/Desktop/justupload.txt 
mv: rename /Users/ddow/Desktop/File_Converted/* to /var/folders/xE/xEV9UA-AFpOdJkN2IrTAArI6Gs+/-Tmp-/mytemp.XXXXXX.AqBhV01D/*: No such file or directory      drwx------    2 user  HQ\acctdev       68 Jun  8 15:00 mytemp.XXXXXX.AqBhV01D

Answer (score 1):

Based on your first error (`mv: rename /Users/user/Desktop/File_Converted/* to ...`), it looks like `/Users/user/Desktop/File_Converted` may be empty, and so the glob, instead of expanding to a list of files, is being treated as a literal string.

EDIT: Looking at your comment below, I notice there is a space in the name of your tiff file:

```
Dan-Dows-MacBook-Pro:tmp ddow$ ls ~/Desktop/File_Converted/ inbox.tiff
```

That's going to cause problems. Replace your single `mv` with this:

```
files_to_move=(~/Desktop/File_Converted/*)
mv "${files_to_move[@]}" $tempdir.
```

The first line creates an array variable, in which each element is a file name from `File_Converted`, and spaces in each file name are properly preserved. In the second line,
we use parameter expansion in quotes to expand to a list of file names (again, properly preserving spaces in file names after word splitting) which are then moved to `$tempdir`.

Comment: It's not empty.  There's a .tiff file there.

Comment: Thanks for helping, but there's no space in the name.  I went ahead and tried your suggestion anyway and I still end up with the same error.  mv: rename /Users/ddow/Desktop/File_Converted/* to /tmp/mytempPfr7pG/*: No such file or directory  The script now reads: tempdir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/mytempXXXXXX)

echo $tempdir > ~/Desktop/log.txt

files_to_move=(~/Desktop/File_Converted/*)
mv "${files_to_move[@]}" $tempdir

Answer (score 0):

I think `mktemp` works a bit different on OSX. It is trying to create your temporary directory with the prefix `$TMPDIR`, which if you do `echo $TMPDIR` you'll see is `/var/folders/...`

You need to just use, for example `mktemp /tmp/mytemp.XXXXXX`

Comment: This still doesn't work: tempdir=$(mktemp -d /tmp/mytemp.XXXXXX)

echo $tempdir > ~/Desktop/log.txt

mv ~/Desktop/File_Converted/* "$tempdir"  mv: rename /Users/ddow/Desktop/File_Converted/* to /tmp/mytemp.pYIkCf/*: No such file or directory
Again, when I check teh directory is there.

Comment: Again: bash should be expanding the asterisk in your glob to a list of real file names before `mv` sees it. The fact that `mv` is displaying "/Users/ddow/Desktop/File_Converted/*" in its error message indicates that there is a problem there, not in your temp directory.

Comment: Is there anything in the directory `/Users/ddow/Desktop/File_Converted/` you'll get that error if the directory is empty.

Comment: Thanks, I totally get what you're saying.  I just don't understand why that should be happening. Dan-Dows-MacBook-Pro:tmp ddow$ ls ~/Desktop/File_Converted/
inbox.tiff  I know it should be expanding the "*" but it isn't.